# How to select all tuples determined id and newest timestamp

Tags: postgresql

Given a table:

```
id | timestmap | ..otherstuff..
```

with primary key (id,timestmap). Where id is of type integer and timestamp is a timestamp.

How can I extract all tupes of which timestamp is the newest for that tuple?

E.g. if this is the current data:

```
1 | 1999-05-23 0:00 | ...
2 | 2000-05-23 0:00 | ...
1 | 2000-06-22 0:00 | ...
```

I want the result exactly to be (though the order is a bonus I do not exactly care for)

```
1 | 2000-06-22 0:00 | ...
2 | 2000-05-23 0:00 | ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases like this i use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html).

As example assuming that your table is called foo, this query will work:

```
WITH tmp as (
    SELECT id, timestmap, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestmap desc) FROM foo
)
SELECT id, timestmap FROM tmp WHERE rank=1;
```

Comment: it must be descending instead of ascending as the newest is also the biggest apparently but besides that a good solution

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT id, timestamp_col, otherstuff from your_table
order by timestamp_col desc
```

?

Comment: well, this would also return (1|1999-05-23 0:00|...) which is not the newest timestamp of that tuple, and is therefore undesired output

Comment: what is the data type of the column timestamp_col ?  can you please post more info about your table data structure ?

Comment: I understand that you mean to output only newest but not the oldest one in your example?  what do you mean by "newest" ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... the only way to do that is via a self-join:

```
SELECT id, timestamp_col, otherstuff 
  FROM table1 AS t1
 NATURAL JOIN
  (SELECT id, MAX(timestamp_col) AS timestamp_col 
     FROM table1 GROUP BY id) AS t2;
```

This is from memory, and some details might be off. Keep in mind that it's not really performant (use EXPLAIN before the first SELECT to see the actual costs).